# IBM MDM Server BatchProcessor Exception_CustomerReflectionDelegate_JNDINameLookup Error

Tags: java, ssl, master-data-management

I am trying to run IBM MDM Server BatchProcessor ; on executing rubBatch.sh script I am getting following error:

```
ERROR     - [Exception_CustomerReflectionDelegate_JNDINameLookup:] CDKBC2030E:Unable to locate a reference using the following parameters. JNDI = com/dwl/base/requestHandler/beans/DWLServiceController; URL = null; additional error message = Error getting WsnNameService properties
javax.naming.NamingException: Error getting WsnNameService properties [Root exception is org.omg.CORBA.TRANSIENT: initial and forwarded IOR inaccessible  vmcid: IBM  minor code: E07  completed: No]
        at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtxFactory.mergeWsnNSProperties(WsnInitCtxFactory.java:1482)
        at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtxFactory.getRootContextFromServer(WsnInitCtxFactory.java:989)
        at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtxFactory.getRootJndiContext(WsnInitCtxFactory.java:909)
        at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtxFactory.getInitialContextInternal(WsnInitCtxFactory.java:581)
        at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.getContext(WsnInitCtx.java:124)
        at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.getContextIfNull(WsnInitCtx.java:799)
        at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.lookup(WsnInitCtx.java:165)
        at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.lookup(WsnInitCtx.java:180)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:436)
        at com.dwl.tcrm.delegate.CustomerReflectionDelegate.init(CustomerReflectionDelegate.java:382)
        at com.dwl.tcrm.delegate.CustomerReflectionDelegate.<init>(CustomerReflectionDelegate.java:190)
        at com.dwl.batchframework.delegate.Customer.init(Customer.java:122)
        at com.dwl.batchframework.delegate.CustomerSingleton.init(CustomerSingleton.java:82)
        at com.dwl.batchframework.BatchController.initServerConfiguration(BatchController.java:395)
        at com.dwl.batchframework.BatchController.initialize(BatchController.java:360)
        at com.dwl.batchframework.BatchController.runBatch(BatchController.java:273)
        at com.dwl.batchframework.BatchController.main(BatchController.java:202)
Caused by: org.omg.CORBA.TRANSIENT: initial and forwarded IOR inaccessible  vmcid: IBM  minor code: E07  completed: No
        at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ClientDelegate.createRequest(ClientDelegate.java:1153)
        at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ClientDelegate.createRequest(ClientDelegate.java:1375)
        at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ClientDelegate.createRequest(ClientDelegate.java:1042)
        at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ClientDelegate.createRequest(ClientDelegate.java:1341)
        at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ClientDelegate.request(ClientDelegate.java:1685)
        at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ClientDelegate.request(ClientDelegate.java:1297)
        at org.omg.CORBA.portable.ObjectImpl._request(ObjectImpl.java:458)
        at com.ibm.WsnBootstrap._WsnNameServiceStub.getProperties(_WsnNameServiceStub.java:38)
        at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtxFactory.mergeWsnNSProperties(WsnInitCtxFactory.java:1479)
        ... 16 more
Caused by: org.omg.CORBA.COMM_FAILURE: CAUGHT_EXCEPTION_WHILE_CONFIGURING_SSL_CLIENT_SOCKET Exception=com.ibm.websphere.ssl.SSLException: CWPKI0315E: SSL configuration properties are null. Could be a problem parsing the SSL client configuration.  vmcid: 0x49421000  minor code: 70  completed: No
        at com.ibm.ws.security.orbssl.WSSSLClientSocketFactoryImpl.createSSLSocket(WSSSLClientSocketFactoryImpl.java:256)
        at com.ibm.ws.orbimpl.transport.WSSSLTransportConnection.createSocket(WSSSLTransportConnection.java:236)
        at com.ibm.CORBA.transport.TransportConnectionBase.connect(TransportConnectionBase.java:351)
        at com.ibm.ws.orbimpl.transport.WSTransport$1.run(WSTransport.java:502)
        at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:118)
        at com.ibm.ws.orbimpl.transport.WSTransport.getConnection(WSTransport.java:499)
        at com.ibm.CORBA.transport.TransportBase.getConnection(TransportBase.java:181)
        at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.TransportManager.get(TransportManager.java:95)
        at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.GIOPImpl.getConnection(GIOPImpl.java:131)
        at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.GIOPImpl.locate(GIOPImpl.java:221)
        at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ClientDelegate.locate(ClientDelegate.java:1769)
        at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ClientDelegate._createRequest(ClientDelegate.java:1794)
        at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ClientDelegate.createRequest(ClientDelegate.java:1064)
        at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ClientDelegate.createRequest(ClientDelegate.java:1149)
        ... 24 more
An error occurred. See the log file for details.  Additional error message = Error getting WsnNameService properties
Exception in thread "P=271190:O=0:CT" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.dwl.batchframework.BatchController.closeIOqueues(BatchController.java:335)
        at com.dwl.batchframework.BatchController.runBatch(BatchController.java:295)
        at com.dwl.batchframework.BatchController.main(BatchController.java:202)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Patrick,

AS per the Exception "SSL configuration properties are null. Could be a problem parsing the SSL client configuration." . 
Please check the **path of the CLIENTSSL variable (ssl.client.props)** in the runbatch.sh file. Looks like the script is unable to find ssl.client.props file.